# RDS connect via VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My MySQL database stored in AWS RDS. I need to connect this database to my website which is hosted by another provider. But I don't have a public IP in AWS.So they told connect via VPN. How can I do this?

Comment: So are you saying that your RDS instance is not public? or you don't want to make it public but you want it to be accessed from the other provider?

Comment: imho that's not the best idea considering the speed and latency, the best option would be having the database close to the website.

Comment: Update your question with details on the hosting provider, the network, what the website is running on etc. Setting up a VPN is easy if you are experienced with VPNs, otherwise you will pull your hair out. The simple method is to make your RDS instance public, lock-down the security group and then connect from your website using whatever language you are using (again details count). If these comments confuse you, you either need to study hard or hire (borrow) someone who does know.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need of external VPN provider. You can create an site-to-site IPsec VPN from your third party network to the RDS AWS VPC. It's not much complicated. There are lot of docs available in the AWS documentation page. If you want you can go through the below links.

[AWS VPC N/W Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/GenericConfigNoBGP.html)

[AWS Scenarios for Accessing a DB Instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html)

[AWS Setting Up an AWS VPN Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/SetUpVPNConnections.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question.  Do you have a device on the local network that can support an IPSec tunnel to AWS?  For example, I use SonicWall TZ400, but there are many, many devices from many, many vendors that support this functionality.

If you don't have such a device, you'll need to get one.

Then, you need to configure your VPC (I assume your RDS instance is in a VPC, and that the RDS instance sits in a subnet that is private (no public IP address is assigned)?

Assuming that you have a local, physical network device that supports IPSec tunnels, you'll need to define a Customer Gateway (CGW) a Virtual Private Gateway (VPW), and a VPN connection.

It's not as hard as it sounds, but there are several steps involved.

See here for detailed steps:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/SetUpVPNConnections.html

Comment: but how can i connect this rds to my php website

Comment: Where, physically, is your PHP website?  On AWS?  If so, put it in the same VPC as your RDS instance, but in a public subnet, with RDS in private subnet, and you should be good to go.  No VPN required.